# Injectivity/surjectivity of $L_A$ and rank a of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to proof this:

> A matrix $A\in M_{m\times n}(K)$ is given. Consider the linear transformation $L_A: K^n \to K^m: v \mapsto Av.$ Show that $L_A$ is surjective if and only if $rk(A)=m$. Show that $L_A$ is injective if and only if $rk(A)=n$.

What I've found:

1. $L_A$ is surjective $\iff$ im$(L_A) = K^m \iff \dim($im$(L_A)) = \dim(K^m) \iff rk(A)=m.$
2. Consider the standard basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ in $K^n$. $L_A$ is injective $\iff \{L_A(e_1),\dots,L_A(e_n)\} = \{Ae_1,\dots,Ae_n\}$ is a linear independent set in $K^m$ $\iff$ the columnspace $C= \langle A_1,\dots,A_n\rangle$, with $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ the columns of A, has dimension $n$ $\iff rk(A) = n$.

Is this a valid proof? Are there other methods to show the above?

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem (also known as “dimension theorem”)?

Comment: I do. I'll try: $\dim($im$(L_A)) + \dim($ker$(L_A)) = n$. So $L_A$ is injective $\iff \dim($ker$(L_A))=0 \iff \dim($im$(L_A)) = rk(A) = n. $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of $L_A$ is the same as the column space of $A$, that is all the column vectors in $K^m$ of the form $Ax$, for $x\in K^n$.

Therefore the rank of $A$ is the same as the dimension of the image of $L_A$. Surjectivity is obviously equivalent to the rank being $m$.

The rank-nullity theorem tells you that
$$
n=\dim\operatorname{im}L_A+\dim\ker L_A
$$
The map $L_A$ is injective if and only if $\dim\ker L_A=0$, that is, if and only if $\dim\operatorname{im}L_A=n$.